# Trouble understanding python inheritance arguments

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

I've tried reading a few different tutorials, but I still can't figure it out. I have two simple classes. Animal and cat.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init___(self, age):
        self.age = age
        print('age is: {0}'.format(self.age))

    def talk(self):
        print('Meowwww!')



c = Cat('Molly')
c.talk()
```

Output is:

```
Meowwww!
```

The code runs, but I'm a little confused. I created an instance of the cat class with `c = Cat('Molly')`. So somehow by using `"Molly"` as an argument for the `Cat()` class instance, it feeds `"Molly"` to the original base class (`Animal`) **instead** of the `Cat` class instance I created? Why? So how do I feed the `Cat` class instance the `age` variable it requires?

I tried doing:

```
c = Cat('Molly', 10)
```

But it complains about too many arguments. And secondly, why doesn't the `__init__` function of the Cat class get called? It should print "age is...". It just never does.

EDIT: Got it to work, thanks to Martijn Pieters! Here is the updated code (works with python3):

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print('name is: {0}'.format(self.name))


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age = age
        print('age is: {0}'.format(self.age))

    def talk(self):
        print('Meowwww!')


c = Cat('Molly', 5)
c.talk()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled `__init__`:

```
def __init___(self, age):
#   12    345
```

That's 3 double underscores at the end, not the required 2.

As such, Python won't call it as it is not the method it is looking for.

If you want to pass in both age and name, give the method another argument, then call the parent `__init__` with just the name:

```
class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age = age
```

Comment: Although I believe Animal would also need to inherit from "object" to use super() (see the [note on super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). Also, super() can only be called without arguments in Python 3.0+. Otherwise, the child class and self must be passed as well. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) for more info.

Comment: @AMacK: Yes, but the OP is using Python 3 here (using `print()` as a function). `object` is *implicit* in Python 3 (all classes are new-style).

Comment: True, but the print() function can also be optionally used in previous versions. I don't think the implicit object parent goes back, though.

Comment: @AMacK: no, it doesn't indeed. In Python 2 you'd have to use the explicit form of `super()` and inherit from `object`.